# How do you supress or acknowledge alerts in Greenbone Security Assistant / OpenVAS?

Tags: networking, security, vulnerabilities

first time post in here so be gentle =)

I searched around for a few days trying to find an answer and I'm really stumped, I have OpenVAS installed on my Kali box, scanning my network etc, and one of the hosts shows up as an open relay, however it's actually configured to relay only for certain internal IP's.

Is there a way to tell OpenVAS not to worry about this particular host's relay status as by default the OpenVAS system will be able to relay to that mail server, but it's not open to the outside world. It's quite annoying as it keeps the resulting alert level at 10 which looks bad, but it isn't. In essence, it's creating a "false positive" that I want it to omit/ignore in future.

Thanks in advance.